Why the finite field $F_{p}$ being the fixed field of Frobenius map implies $\mathrm{Gal}(F / F_p)$ is a cyclic group generated by the Frobenius map
I'm reading the proof of Theorem 6.5 from the book Field and Galois Theory by Patrick Morandi
I get stuck on reading the last part of this proof. In the book, it uses $\mathcal{F}(\sigma)$ to denote the fixed field of $\sigma$ which is an automorphism of $F$.
Then it said that since $F_{p}$ is the fixed field of $\sigma$, then it directly deduced that $\mathrm{Gal}(F / F_{p})$ is the cyclic group generated by $\sigma$. I don't how $F_{p}$ being the fixed field of $\sigma$ (being the fixed field of one element in $\mathrm{Aut}(F/F_{p})$) implies that $\mathrm{Gal}(F / F_{p})$ is a cyclic generated by $\sigma$.
Any help on this? Thanks.

Please do not use pictures to convey critical information not otherwise present in your post. See here for some of the reasons

For any subgroup $H$ of the automorphism group of $K$ over $F$, $K$ is Galois over the fixed field of $H$ with Galois group $H$. So $F$ is Galois over $F_p$ with Galois group $\langle\sigma\rangle$.

I know this is the result of the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory. However, how can you know that the fixed field of $\langle \sigma \rangle$ is $F_{p}$, since we only know that the fixed field of $\sigma$ is the $F_{p}$.

The fixed field of $\sigma^n$ contains the fixed field of $\sigma$ for every $n$, so it can't be any smaller. And the fixed field of $\langle\sigma\rangle$ is contained in the fixed field of $\sigma$, so it can't be any larger.

(By the way, what I quoted doesn't require the fundamental theorem, because it does not assume that $K$ is Galois over $F$. It is a theorem of Artin, though it requires $H$ finite. See second paragraph of the lede in Wikipedia.)

HINT.- $F$ should be supposed a finite extension of the prime field $\Bbb F_p$; let $n$ its degree. If $x\in F\setminus \Bbb F_p$ then the conjugates of $x$ are $$x,x^p,x^{p^2},x^{p^3},\cdots,x^{p^n-1}$$ which implies that
$$\sigma(x)=x^p\Rightarrow \sigma(x^p)=\sigma^2(x)\Rightarrow \sigma(x^{p^2})=\sigma^3(x)\Rightarrow\cdots \sigma(x^{p^n-1})=\sigma^n(x)$$
Can you finish?
